# How to find files contains both keywords on different line by grep?

Tags: grep, sh

There are many files in Linux kernel source `config/*` I want to found one which is similar to my board.

So I try:

```
egrep -l -e key1 -e key2 config/*

Sample config/file1:
    This is key1
    This is key2
Sample config/file2:
    This is key1
Sample config/file3:
    This is key2
```

But the result is either `key1` or `key2` file listing.
I want the result which contains `key1` **and** `key2`
or is there other easy unix shell which can generate the result?

In the previsous sample I just want to list 'file1'.

Comment: Maybe this link could help you : http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/290/grep-multiple-keywords-and-not-or/

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```
( grep -l key1 config/* ; grep -l key2 config/* ) |sort |uniq -c |grep '^ *2\>' |awk '{print $2}'
```

First `grep` prints all files that contain `key1`, second `grep` prints all files that contain `key2`,
and then `sort`, `uniq` and third `grep` filter for files listed *twice*, i.e. containing both keys.

Answer (score 0):

'grep -E 'pat1.*pat2|pat2.*pat1'' is my usual incantation. axiom's solution only works if those patterns appear in the order given, the '|' regular expression operator allows the search to find the patterns in any order.